Any action needed for 1.5in notch in main beam?
I’ve been in this house for a few years and just discovered this notch behind a ceiling tile.
Home is a raised ranch with a finished basement and two adjacent garage bays beneath the top floor.
Within the finished basement area, there is a single main beam that measures 5x7.5in. The notch is very close to the concrete wall of the garage where the beam must rest, and the diameter of the notch is 1.5in (outer diameter of pipe).
The location close the wall is comforting, as is the round shape of the notch, but this seems to go agains the rule of thumb (D/6) that I’m seeing elsewhere. Following that, max notch size would be 1.25in.
Original home structure is 1969. Addition in 1978, which is when I suspect this work was done, but can’t be sure.


Additional photos - turns out this wasn’t merely a notch




Is that a crack in the beam that we see, with bits of insulation or similar fluff in it? If so, is this close enough to the basement wall that the crack is running to the end of the beam?

@spuck - yes that’s a crack. I may post some additional photos as well.
The basement wall is effectively immediately to the left of the first photo. Where you see the concrete in the second photo is where the beam terminates. The concrete wall is taller than the bottom of the beam. Also added photos

I'm no structural engineer, but it seems like if there is an open crack right there the beam is not carrying any load, no? If there was substantial weight bearing down on the beam, the crack would be pressed shut-- assuming the crack runs to the end of the beam, and the beam is resting on top of the wall. That doesn't necessarily mean it's to code or correct, but it would reduce my concern about how much the notch has weakened the beam.

Is it to code? - not quite. But code has to allow for square edge notches, etc. I did note one diagram claiming D/3 on top and D/6 for the bottom, (in the outer thirds only) though. Most stick to D/6 top and bottom.
Is it a practical problem? - likely not if it's held for the past 46 years.
Reenforce the beam there if it makes you happy. Or the next buyer of your house happy. Might be worth looking up what the beam notch specs in the code that applied where you are in 1978 were, in case they were different. In that case there's no requirement to update it, if it was built to the code in force in the area at the time it was built.

I certainly lean toward this thinking if the work was truly done back in 78. That said, what is the typical time for an issue to arise from something like this? If this was only about 10yrs old (possible given last owner), would your opinion remain the same?

From the condition of the fasteners, the face finish on the lumber (smoothness, patina, lack of printing, non-rounded edges, etc) you can be confident this lumber did not come from a commercial sawmill within the last 10 years.
